# Antd - is there any way to change Content background color with ConfigProvider?

Tags: reactjs, antd, styled-components

i'm trying to make Content background color change to white with ConfigProvider, so i don't have to change background color in every component. I found solution for Header and Sider, but Content is giving me a little problems. Is there any magic solution for that?

Here's ConfigProvider in main index file.

```
<ConfigProvider
    theme={{
      components: {
        Layout: {
          colorBgHeader: '#fff'
        }
      }
    }}
  >
    <App />
  </ConfigProvider>
```

The only way that works for me to change background in Component is to change it manually (i'm using styled-components)

```
import styled from 'styled-components'
import { Layout } from 'antd';

const { Content } = Layout;

export const StyledContent = styled(Content)`
  margin: 5px;
  background: ${({ theme }) => theme.colors.white};
`;
```

Comment: have your tried `colorBgLayout`?

Comment: @NishargShah yes, it changes whole website background color.

Comment: There is no way to do that but I hope you will like my answer.

Answer (score 1):

There is two way to do that

**1st way**

You can add `className` and globally define that into your `scss` file and you can change it.

**2nd way**

You can define the background color for `header` and define the background color for `body` and it will automatically apply into `content`.

```
<ConfigProvider
  theme={{
    components: {
      Layout: {
        colorBgHeader: "black",
        colorBgBody: "skyblue"
      }
    }
  }}
>
```

Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/mutable-browser-w1tt72?file=/src/App.js

Comment: well, it's not working for me, but thanks for trying :)